# Scala Slick 3 get total rows count while paginating

Tags: scala, slick, scala-2.11, slick-3.0

I need some sort of pagination.

So I use methods `take()` and `drop()` in query. But I need to query total rows count in table too. How can I get it?

Some code for starting point:

```
for {
  p <- persons
    .drop(10)
    .take(10)
} yield (p.name, p.age, totalRowsCount?)
```

Comment: you can use ```persons.size``` to get the total rows.

Comment: @AllenChou Then it will be 2 queries. But what if I filter `persons` before `take()` and `drop()`? Then I need 2 queries with filters: one for size and second for `take()` and `drop()`? I whant to make it with one query.

Comment: Can you count the total rows and return a range of rows with only ONE query in pure SQL ? I don't think it's possible, and therefore it's not possible with Slick. You can use the same Query object, and call one time `size`, then add the drop/take and call `result`.

Comment: @JulienLafont you are right.